# Enabling sound with Xcode 'sandbox'ed application

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, appstore-approval, appstore-sandbox

I have an application which plays a midi sound.
The application works fine without sandboxing, and plays the sound it is supposed to play, but I cannot here the sound when I enable sandboxing.

I need to upload the application to mac app store, but i cannot do it, because i cannot get sound.

I also cannot open the file dialog box, when I enable sandboxing.
Is there any way I can at least enable the sound in the app?

[image: Below is the screenshot of the sandboxing settings in Xcode 5]

Comment: The sound file has to be within the bundle of the application or sandboxing will prevent you from accessing it. You need to enable the 'User Selected File' option as at least `Read Only` to permit accessing user chosen files on the file system. Please [read the sandboxing guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html) which details this.

Comment: interesting that you mention that. 
I have enabled 'User Selected File' with Read/Write option. 

I will update the question with the screenshot of my sandbox settings.

Comment: Have you looked at the app running under instruments with the file activity instrument? It would tell you what it needs when not sandboxed, and it may give you a hint as to how to proceed in getting it working under the sandbox. midi support requires access to sound font files and the likes to make any audio, so it could be the case that access to these files is blocked in the sandbox. Additionally, midi file support is **not built in** to any version of mac os x that supports sandboxing.

Comment: Based on a [link from another website](http://www.mbsplugins.de/archive/2013-09-15/Sandbox_and_playing_Midi), it sounds like you may need more entitlements for the app to get it to work in the sandbox

Comment: that link which you gave worked perfectly for me, I haven't really looked up my app in instrument, but i think its a good idea to explore that.
Anyhow, thanks a lot. I will add this link in the answer. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Petesh said in above comments, I had to add some more entries in the entitlements file, 
the link which was given by him above, contained following. You add them to your entitlement file, and everything will start working like a charm.

**This one allows your application to access the microphone.**

```
com.apple.security.device.microphone
```

**This allows talking to the MIDI Server which coordinates all the Midi functionality across applications.**

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name
```

**This allows talking to audio components which are not itself sandboxed.**

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.audio-unit-host
```

They worked for me.

Comment: I just fear that the word 'temporary-exception' may mean that they stop working in the future

Comment: I get `2013-10-23 20:53:02.128 my_app[555:303] Exception raised!: NSNavOpenPanel is not a supported subclass for sandboxing`

when I try to open a file dialog.. is there any alternative to this, I am relatively new to mac, and we have used carbon in our app.

Comment: a little bit of googling reveals: [use the AppKit NSOpen/SavePanel API directly from your Carbon app, rather than Navigation Services.](http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=22312).

Comment: Alright thnks a lot, I will try that, and post the results. :) 
Cheers.